# Run a node-scheduler every day between a specific hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduler, node-schedule

I have a function of sending notification which i want to run every day between 9AM to 6PM.
To achieve this i am using node-scheduler package. All i am trying to do this.

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");

const rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
rule.hour = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
rule.minute = 0;
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, () => console.log(`hey bro`));
```

Does node-scheduler support hour array ? I tried this on REPL but somehow it was not working.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like:

```
         const rule = new scheduler.RecurrenceRule();
         rule.hour = new scheduler.Range(9, 18);
         rule.dayOfWeek = new scheduler.Range(0, 6);
         schedule.scheduleJob(rule, () => console.log(`hey bro`));
```